# How to properly generify this class to avoid unchecked warning?

Tags: java, generics

I have this tiny class which provide a wrapper around something that may throw an exception and return a javaslang 2.05 Either (which by convention has a failure in `left` and a normal result in `right`.  Any Either can be only one of these).

```
public class EitherWrapper {
    public static <E extends Exception, R> Either<E, R> wrap(Callable<R> callable) {
        try {
            return Either.right(callable.call());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return (Either<E, R>) Either.left(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Javadoc for `Either.left` at https://static.javadoc.io/io.javaslang/javaslang/2.0.5/javaslang/control/Either.html#left--

Problem is that javac flags `return (Either<E, R>) Either.left(e);` as an unchecked cast (which is fair as javac thinks it is an `Either<Exception,Object`>) but I would really like to fix this properly instead of just casting it.  How should I rewrite this class so the warning goes away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that you are pegging `Either.Left` to exception anyway, so you are not achieving the universality allowed by generics.

Peg it to `Exception` all the way and have the following:

```
public static <R> Either<Exception, R> wrap(Callable<R> callable) {
    try {
        return Either.right(callable.call());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Either.left(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is because `Callable.call()` throws plain Exception.  Should I add my own functional interface throwing E?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen why would you need your functional interface throwing `E`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) to resolve the type of right part:

```
return Either.<E, R>left(e);
```

Comment: That gives a compilation error - "`Error:(18, 38) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Exception cannot be converted to E`" as `call()` throws an Exception.  Suggestions?

Comment: You could try `return Either.<Exception, R>left(e);`

Comment: Have you tested your suggestions?

Comment: No, I'm not a Java expert but in C# we can call a static method on a generic class like this : `return MyGenericClass<T, U>.StaticMethod();` and your problem is that the compiler can't define the type when you call the static method. So you need to find a syntax to help the compiler to define the type of the right part of `Either`

Answer (score 0):

Since it's known that the `Either` wraps an `Exception` I would just do:

```
class EitherWrapper {
    public static <R> Either<Exception, R> wrap(final Callable<R> callable) {
        try {
            return Either.right(callable.call());
        } catch (final Exception ex) {
            return Either.left(ex);
        }

    }
}
```

It's not necessary to generify the thrown `Exception` as `E` as its type is explicitly defined within the function.

Of course `Either<? extends Exception, R>` would work as well.

---

Compiles and runs correctly with e.g:

```
final Either<Exception, Object> e = EitherWrapper.wrap(Object::new);
```

Comment: alright, just saw diginoise's answer... stick to that